# Why is Xpath returning null for Salesforce SOAP query response?

Tags: api, query, webservices, wsdl, xmlparsing

I am using Xpath to attempt to parse and get data back from a SOAP Salesforce query response, I found the sample API request and response WSDL from [this Salesforce Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/06/salesforce-soap-api-sample-wsdls.html).

My SOAP Salesforce API request looks like the following

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:urn="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:urn1="urn:sobject.partner.soap.sforce.com"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:wd="http://www.workday.com">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <urn:SessionHeader>
            <urn:sessionId>
                <!-- Insert Some Session ID Here -->
            </urn:sessionId>
        </urn:SessionHeader>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <urn:query>
            <urn:queryString>
                SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE Name ='Booker Dewitt'
            </urn:queryString>
        </urn:query>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The SOAP Salesforce API Response looks like the following

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:sf="urn:sobject.partner.soap.sforce.com">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <LimitInfoHeader>
            <limitInfo>
                <current>1523</current>
                <limit>6235000</limit>
                <type>API REQUESTS</type>
            </limitInfo>
        </LimitInfoHeader>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <queryResponse>
            <result xsi:type="QueryResult">
                <done>true</done>
                <queryLocator xsi:nil="true" />
                <records xsi:type="sf:sObject">
                    <sf:type>Contact</sf:type>
                    <sf:Id>000000000001122334</sf:Id>
                    <sf:Id>000000000001122334</sf:Id>
                </records>
                <size>1</size>
            </result>
        </queryResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The Data node that I am trying to access the first `<sf:Id>000000000001122334</sf:Id>` node.

The XPath for that node is `/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/queryResponse/result/records/sf:Id`. However this value is pulling null. If I back up to the `soapenv:Body` node I am able to pull all of the child nodes as follows.

Xpath: `/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/`

Response:

```
<soapenv:Body>
        <queryResponse>
            <result xsi:type="QueryResult">
                <done>true</done>
                <queryLocator xsi:nil="true" />
                <records xsi:type="sf:sObject">
                    <sf:type>Contact</sf:type>
                    <sf:Id>000000000001122334</sf:Id>
                    <sf:Id>000000000001122334</sf:Id>
                </records>
                <size>1</size>
            </result>
        </queryResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
```

But any node past `soapenv:Body` returns null. Why is this happening and is there any way to get to the sf:Id Node using Xpath?

Comment: Fair enough question on the XPath usage. It looks like you are running a SOQL query against the partner API. Is there a reason you don't use the SOAP support that's built into Apex?

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be a quirk of the XPath specification. Once there is a namespace specified, it becomes harder to access nodes in the default namespace. (As a side note, this is firmly outside the limits of my knowledge, and I'm not really inclined to dig through the W3C documents to verify this)

Based on the answer on [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16717211/getting-elements-with-default-namespace-no-namespace-prefix-using-xpath)...

> If you have a namespace prefix set, you could use it, like:
>
> //soap:Body
>
> **But since the nodes you are trying to get use a default namespace, without a prefix, using plain XPath, you can only acesss them by the local-name() and namespace-uri() attributes**. Examples:
>
> //*[local-name()="HelloWorldResult"]/text()
>
> ...

Using that information, and an XPath tester that I found, the following query works

`/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/*[local-name()="queryResponse"]/*[local-name()="result"]/*[local-name()="records"]/sf:Id`

The `*` before using `[local-name()="something"]` appears to be required, and will select all nodes matching that name. To get a specific node, you'd just add `[<some integer>]` afterwords like so:

`.../*[local-name()="something][2]/...`